# MongoDB - count() takes too long despite using an index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

I have a collection with 62k documents in it. The same collection has a bunch of indexes too, most of them simple, single field ones. What I am observing is that the following query takes extremely long to return:

```
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","$or":[{"groups":{"$exists":false}},{"groups":{"$size":0}},{"groups":{"$in":["5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"]}}]})
```

The executionStats for the above query are as follows

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "xxxxxx.jobs",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "groups" : {
                            "$size" : 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "groups" : {
                            "$eq" : "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$nor" : [
                            {
                                "groups" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "status" : {
                    "$eq" : "complete"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "groups" : {
                        "$size" : 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "groups" : {
                        "$eq" : "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "groups" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "status" : 1,
                "groups" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "status_1_groups_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "status" : [ ],
                "groups" : [
                    "groups"
                ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "status" : [
                    "[\"complete\", \"complete\"]"
                ],
                "groups" : [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "groups" : {
                            "$size" : 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "groups" : {
                            "$eq" : "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$nor" : [
                            {
                                "groups" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "status" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "status_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "status" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "status" : [
                        "[\"complete\", \"complete\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 62092,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 9992,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 62092,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 62092,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "groups" : {
                        "$size" : 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "groups" : {
                        "$eq" : "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "groups" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "nReturned" : 62092,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 9929,
        "works" : 62093,
        "advanced" : 62092,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 682,
        "restoreState" : 682,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 62092,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 62092,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 60,
            "works" : 62093,
            "advanced" : 62092,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 682,
            "restoreState" : 682,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "keyPattern" : {
                "status" : 1,
                "groups" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "status_1_groups_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "status" : [ ],
                "groups" : [
                    "groups"
                ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "status" : [
                    "[\"complete\", \"complete\"]"
                ],
                "groups" : [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined" : 62092,
            "seeks" : 1,
            "dupsTested" : 62092,
            "dupsDropped" : 0,
            "seenInvalidated" : 0
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "xxxxxxx",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.15",
    "gitVersion" : "xxxxxx"
},
"ok" : 1}
```

What I am trying to understand is why does the FETCH stage take 10 seconds when the index scan in INPUT_STAGE takes 60ms. Since I am eventually doing a count() I don't really need mongoDB to return the documents, I only need it to $sum up the number of matching keys and give me the grand total.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The query explained there was not a count, it returned quite a few documents:

```
"nReturned" : 62092,
```

The estimated execution for each stage suggests that the index scan was expected to take 60ms, and fetching the documents from disk took the additional 9.8 seconds.

There are a couple of reasons this count required fetching the documents:

- Key existence cannot be fully determined from the index
  The `{"$exists":false}` predicate is also troublesome.  When building an index the value for a document contains the value of each indexed field.  There is no value for "nonexistent", so it uses `null`.  Since a document that contains a field whose value is explicitly set to `null` should *not* match `{"$exists":false}`, the query executor must load each document from disk in order to determine if the field was `null` nor nonexistent.  This means that a COUNTSCAN stage cannot be used, which further means that *all* of the documents to be counted must be loaded from disk.
- The `$or` predicate does not ensure exclusivity
  The query executor cannot know ahead of time that the clauses in the `$or` are mutually exclusive.  They are in your query, but in the general case it is possible for a single document to match more than one clause in the `$or`, so the query executor must load the documents to ensure deduplication.

#### So how to eliminate the fetch stage?

If you were to query with only the `$in` clause, or with only the `$size` clause you should find the count is derived from the index scan, without needing to load any documents.

This is, if you were to run these queries separately from the client, and sum the results, you should find that the overall execution time is less than the query that requires fetching:

```
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","groups":{"$size":0}})
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","groups":{"$in":["5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"]}})
```

For the `{"groups":{"$exists":false}}` predicate, you might modify the data slightly, such as ensure that the field always exists, but assign it a value that means "undefined" that can be indexed and queried.

As an example, if you were to run the following update, the groups field would then exist in all documents:

```
db.jobs.update({"groups":{"$exists":false}},{"$set":{"groups":false}})
```

And you could get the equivalent of the above count by running these 2 queries that should both be covered by an index scan, and should run faster together than the query that requires loading documents:

```
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","groups":{"$size":0}})
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","groups":{"$in":[false, "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"]}})
```

Comment: Oh man, I had such high hopes for your answer! Unfortunately though, I've tried removing the troublesome predicates to no avail. Running `db.jobs.find({"status":"complete","groups":{"$size":0}}).explain("executionStats")` gave me inputStage.executionTimeMillisEstimate : 50 but the parent node FETCH stage still took > 6seconds. Any idea why it did not use a COUNTSCAN stage?

Comment: Looking closer, `"groups":{"$size":0}` can't be serviced properly by the index, because MongoDB doesn't store the array itself in the index value, it stores a separate index value for each of the array elements. I suspect the way to get this to perform is to combine `[]` and `missing` in the update, like `db.jobs.update({$or:[{"groups":{"$exists":false}},{"groups":[]}],{"$set":{"groups":false}})`, then the second query there could get the count you need without loading documents.

Comment: Any idea how mongoDB will deal with documents that actually have an array of hashes in the "groups" field? Will the search return the doc if the document has `groups: ["foo", "bar", "abc"]` and the query filter is `{groups: {$in: ["abc", "def"]}}`? Will the index be used here correctly? If it does, then I might actually have the answer I need!

Comment: EDIT: answering my own question - multiple values in the "$in" condition render the query as slow as it was. Interestingly enough, removing the `false` value from the list makes the query return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow avoid the empty array case, than the following query can be used: `db.jobs.count({"status":"complete", "groups": { $in: [ null, "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8" ] } })`

`null` is equivalent to `$exists: false`.

Also: I'd suggest to use ObjectId instead of string as type for the `groups` field.

**Update**

$size never hit an index!

You can use the following query:

```
db.jobs.count({"status":"complete","$or":[
  {"groups":[],
  {"groups": {$in: [ null, "5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8" ]}
]})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the documents in the DB have [] for the groups value, so I can't really avoid it.. About the ObjectId suggestion - what implications does this bring? Is it safer or faster to use it ObjectId instead of plain string?

Comment: ObjectIds are smaller and have better index behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
db.jobs.aggregate(
   .{$match: {"$or":[
   {"groups":{"$exists":false}},
   {"groups":{"$in":["5e65ffc2a1e6ef0007bc5fa8"]}},
   {"$size":0}
   ]}
   },
   .{$count:{"status":"complete"}
   )`
```

Comment: Please do a better format of your text and explain what you do different to the other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from minor syntax errors, there is a problem with this pipeline - you can't use $count in this manner. as per mongoDB docs: 
$count has the following prototype form: { $count: <string> } <string> is the name of the output field which has the count as its value

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: relooking at my aircode; obvious one doesn't need the $in because $exists is a broader criteria...   in plain English: count Status = Complete of all records/documents that have the field Group.... yes?

Comment: Not exactly, the parent condition is $or, so it's either no groups field at all, empty array or one of the $in